# Change address after payment

Tags: transactions

Presume that I have 1 BTC (the total of my UTXO) and I have to pay Bob With 1 BTC. 
I set 0 for fees.

My Input is 1 and my Output is 1 versus Bob or there are always 2 outputs?

one versus Bob

and

one versus my change address with 0 btc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no change in this scenario on only one output sent to bob's address. Note that 0 fee transactions are unlikely to be mined these days so do include a fee. Usually you let your wallet calculate a reasonable fee for you.